# Public variable is undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, global-variables, public

I have the following code:

```
setGlobalReceiverData(id) {

    switch (id) {
      case 'role':
        for (let i = 0; i < this.roleData.length; i++) {
          if (this.roleData[i]['Id'] == this.role) {
            this.DataService.receiverRoleValue = this.roleData[i]['role'];
          }
        }
        break;
      case 'salutation':
        for (let i = 0; i < this.salutationData.length; i++) {
          if (this.salutationData[i]['Id'] == this.salutation) {
            this.DataService.receiverSalutationValue = this.salutationData[i]['salutation'];
          }
        }
        break;
        case 'firstname':
          this.DataService.receiverFirstnameValue = this.firstname;
          break;
        case 'street':
          this.DataService.receiverStreetValue = this.street;
          break;
        case 'zip':
          this.DataService.receiverZipValue = this.zip;
          break;
        case 'location':
          this.DataService.receiverLocationValue = this.location;
          break;
        case 'title':
          for (let i = 0; i < this.titleData.length; i++) {
            if (this.titleData[i]['Id'] == this.title) {
              this.DataService.receiverTitleValue = this.titleData[i]['title'];
            }
          }
          break;
        case 'lastname':
          this.DataService.receiverLastnameValue = this.lastname;
          break;
        case 'inbox':
          this.DataService.receiverInboxValue = this.inbox;
          break;
        case 'co':
          this.DataService.receiverCoValue = this.additional_location;
          break;
    }
  }
```

First of all, does the Case 'Salutation' make sense in the first place?

My main problem is however that the variable this.DataService.receiverSalutationValue is undefined, even though FirstName and LastName is defined and working properly
I have another function:

```
public getGlobalReceiverData(): void
  {
    console.log('Salutation:', this.DataService.receiverSalutationValue);
    console.log('FirstName:', this.DataService.receiverFirstnameValue);
    console.log('Lastname', this.DataService.receiverLastnameValue);

    this.salutation = this.DataService.receiverSalutationValue;
    this.firstname = this.DataService.receiverFirstnameValue;
    this.lastname = this.DataService.receiverLastnameValue;
    this.street = this.DataService.receiverStreetValue;
    this.zip = this.DataService.receiverZipValue;
    this.location = this.DataService.receiverLocationValue;
    this.additional_location = this.DataService.receiverCoValue;
    this.inbox = this.DataService.receiverInboxValue;
  }
```

As you can see receiver salutation is included here. However, when I start the app the salutation variable gets console logged as undefined... In my globaldata Service the global/public variables are set as they're supposed to:

```
 public receiverRoleValue;
  public receiverSalutationValue;
  public receiverFirstnameValue: string;
  public receiverLastnameValue: string;
  public receiverStreetValue: string;
  public receiverInboxValue: string;
  public receiverZipValue: string;
  public receiverLocationValue: string;
  public receiverCoValue: string;
  public receiverTitleValue;
```

I also have a prefill function:

```
public prefillSenderData() {
    return this.http.get(this.get_sender_url)
    .subscribe(
      senderResponse => {
        this.senderSalutationValue = senderResponse[0]['Salutation'];
        this.senderFirstnameValue = senderResponse[0]['FirstName'];
        this.senderLastnameValue = senderResponse[0]['LastName'];
        this.senderPhonenumberValue = senderResponse[0]['PhoneNumber'];
        this.senderPhoneValue = senderResponse[0]['Phone'];
        this.senderNameValue = senderResponse[0]['Name'];
        this.senderAddressValue = senderResponse[0]['Address'];
        this.senderLocationValue = senderResponse[0]['Location'];
        this.senderNameLeftValue = senderResponse[0]['NameLeft'];
        this.senderNameRightValue = senderResponse[0]['NameRight'];
        this.senderFaksimilieLeftValue = senderResponse[0]['FaksimileLeft'];
        this.senderFaksimilieRightValue = senderResponse[0]['FaksimileRight'];

        console.log("Sender-Object: ", senderResponse);

        this.bool_senderSharedDataLoaded = true;
       },
  error => console.log('There was an error: ', error));
  }
```

The salutation data array gets created and its data is mapped:

```
// data
    public salutationData: { [salutation: string]: Object }[] = [ {salutation: "Mr.", Id: 1 }, {salutation: "Mrs.", Id: 2 } ];
    public roleData: { [role: string]: Object }[] = [ {role: "Contract customer", Id: 1 }, {role: "Insurance user", Id: 2 } ];
    public titleData: { [title: string]: Object }[] = [ {title: "Dr.", Id: 1 }, {title: "Prof.", Id: 2 } ];

    // mapping
    public salutation: Object = { text: 'salutation', value: 'Id' };
    public role: Object = { text: 'role', value: 'Id' };
    public title: Object = { text: 'title', value: 'Id' };
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @mbojko How is it relevant?

Comment: Because it looks like your console.logs get executed before the HTTP request returns response.

Comment: ok but if it was async/sync issue how come FirstName and LastName get printed out???

Comment: @mbojko I tried setting a timeout of 3s, that did not help at all.. So probably the issue lies somewhere else..